# Scanning open ports

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat but when I browse http://localhost8080, I do not get the homepage that I'm supposed to get. I do see the icon in recently installed tab of windows. May be another service is listening on port 80. How can I find out which service is listening on which port and how do I reconfigure tomcat to listen on another port?

Answer (score 0):

You can change port no by editing server.xml file

Goto tomcat>conf folder
Edit server.xml
Search "Connector port" Replace "8080" by your port number
Restart tomcat server.

Done!

You can also find which service is using 8080 port on your PC

Open cmd and type this command

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8080
```

After that check which PID using this port 
Now open task manager and goto details tab and see the process which is using 8080 port.

Comment: I found out that system is listening on 8080.. So I reconfigured tomcat to 8081 which is open. But I still do not get the tomcat welcome page. Do I have to be online for it (but its localhost)?

Comment: what you type in url?

Comment: is you type this localhost:8081

Comment: type colon between localhost and port no like this localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

you could use the ressourcemonitoring tool from Windows to show you which application uses the port.

`START -> resmon.exe` and Filter on `network` by the port you want to look at.

On the other side you can look which Port is used by which programm.